# Twitter Bootstrap layout width hidden element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an aspnet  application and twitter bootstrap.
I have a situation where i need to hide a span based on a variable witch I can do correctly. The problem is that the hidden span keeps the width and breaks the next div.

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class='<%= (showTitle  ? "span4" : "hide")  %>'>
            <label>Title</label>
            <ASP:DropDownList ID="DpdLstTitle" runat="server"  CssClass="span12"></ASP:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class='<%= (showTitle  ? "span8" : "span12")  %>'>
            <label>Name</label>
            <ASP:TextBox ID="TboxName" runat="server" MaxLength="80"  CssClass="span12" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what if you use {display:none;} instead of {visibility:hidden;}?

Comment: Did you override the `.hide` class in your CSS? By default, Bootstrap sets this class to have `display: none;` which removes the element from the render tree altogether so it shouldn't be taking up any space at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add in some css as bootstrap has added a margin to the second row

Probably:

```
margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
```

So you'll have to override it.  Insert

```
margin-left: 0;
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class='<%= (showTitle  ? "span4" : "hide")  %>'>
        <label>Title</label>
        <ASP:DropDownList ID="DpdLstTitle" runat="server"  CssClass="span12"></ASP:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class='<%= (showTitle  ? "span8" : "span12 hiddenColBefore")  %>'>
        <label>Name</label>
        <ASP:TextBox ID="TboxName" runat="server" MaxLength="80"  CssClass="span12" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.hiddenColBefore {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works :) . I just have to had !important to the css. Chears